# Rspec: How can i test an optional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Currently  i am learning with the youtube video  [Efficient Rails Test Driven Development - by Wolfram Arnold](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ra8Q0M3DJYk&list=LLKKu__aTyj6LRSxuHlx-x8Q&feature=mh_lolz)
One exercise is:

A Person object has an optional middle_name.

I create a migration  to add the middle name to the database

- rake g migration AddMiddleNameToPerson middle_name:string

and i write a spec

*it "can have a middle name"*

But i got no idea how to test this issue 
how can i test an optional field

thanks for help

Bulleric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that an attribute is 'optional' implies that the instance is valid when the attribute is `nil`. So:

```
it "does not require a middle name" do
  @person = Person.new
  @person.valid?
  @person.errors[:middle_name].should_not include("can't be blank")
end
```

If you're using [shoulda](http://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) then this can be made even simpler:

```
describe Person do
  it { should_not validate_presence_of(:middle_name) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Factor_girl, create two factories,

```
person1 = Factory.create(:person, :first_name=> "A")  
person2 = Factory.create(:person, :first_name=> "A", :middle_name => "M")
```

Now, in your test, show that `person1` and `person2` both get saved to the database.
You could do the same with fixtures, if you are not using factory_girl.